# download and use .EXE(tesseract) with JNLP

Tags: java, exe, jnlp, tesseract

I need to run an application (tesseract) inside my JNLP application.

How can I do to download the tesseract.exe file to the client machine and run it? Is there any way to do this JNLP?

Is there any way to join tesseract into my jar and then run it on the client?

Comment: In other words, you want to bypass the restristions of a java VM, which is startet via JNLP, to spawn a process of a downloaded file? Sounds like creating a botnet...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to download, and [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to run it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have this alternative, but i not want to take that.. i´m looking for a another impl.. where the jnlp download and treatmen that files.

Comment: I think this is impracticable.

Answer (score 0):

For now I include the exe file in my application JAR and when I need to execute, I extract the file to a temp folder, and call it with command line.

Comment: like @cketbach says, with this solution you're bypassing the JVM restrictions. You have to respect the user, and, at least, he should know that you're downloading and executing a exe file to your machine, AND, you should not download it in a jar file.

Comment: Thats de better solution we found. And work. If anyone have another solution, for solve the problem, for make a tesseract run in the client side. Are Welcome.